# Query creation by method name always returns zero counts

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to count students in a table whose first name match a given string . Lateron i want to use "contains" to find students whose names contain a given string.

I created the endpoint in the controller:

```
@GetMapping("/firstname")
  public int findStudentsByfirstName(@RequestParam(value="string")String firstName){
    if (firstName != null){
      System.out.println(firstName);
      return studentRepository.countByfirstNameIgnoreCase(firstName);
    } else return 0;
}
```

and the query creation by method name:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, String> {
  int countByfirstNameIgnoreCase(String firstName);
}
```

The field firstName in the Entity student exists in his superclass person:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
public abstract class Person {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
  @Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
  @JsonProperty("id")
  protected String id;

  @Column
  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty("lastName")
  protected String lastName;

  @Column
  @NotNull
  @JsonProperty("firstName")
  protected String firstName;
```

When I'm asking for localhost:8080/student I get:

```
{"id":"c30e24a8-6b4a-4eec-a28c-afec74709141",
"lastName":"Schlund",
"firstName":"Rainer",
"eMail":"max@student.kit.edu",
"phoneNumber":"011981954856821",
"street":"Musterstraße 1",
"place":"123456 Musterstadt",
"role":"Student",
"immatriculationNumber":"196495619562",
"major":"Informatik",
"semester":27,
"spoId":"SPO08"}
```

So there is a person whose first name is "Rainer"

But when i try localhost:8080/student/firstname?string="Rainer" the result is 0.

Comment: You haven't shown us the method that performs the query.  Probably the bug is there.

Comment: It should automatically be created by Hibernate from this code line "int countByfirstNameIgnoreCase(String firstName);" shown in the second code block above.

Comment: Have you tried without the double quotes? localhost:8080/student/firstname?string=Rainer

Comment: What a stupid error, that's it. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure that the right method is

```
int countByfirstNameIgnoreCase(String firstName);
```

and not

```
int findByfirstNameIgnoreCase(String firstName);
```

??

Comment: I believe as of Spring-Data 1.7.1, `countBy` is applicable.